# Removing a memory address from standard output in Golang

Tags: git, go, compression, zlib

I am attempting to create a clone of git in Go. I am new to Go, especially the "os" and "io" packages.

Question: Why is my function returning a memory address (or maybe it's the number of bytes read?) at the beginning of my output? Is there a way to remove it from the output so that I get the expected output?

Expected output: `dumpty vanilla dooby humpty donkey yikes`

Got: `blob 40\x00dumpty vanilla dooby humpty donkey yikes`

Command: `./my_git.sh cat-file -p <HASH>`

Relevant Code:

```
if os.Args[2] == "-p" {
            // Declare SHA
            sha := os.Args[3]

            // Convert SHA to readable file path
            folder := string(sha[0:2])
            blob := string(sha[2:])
            filePath := ".git/objects/" + folder + "/" + blob

            file, err := os.Open(filePath)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            r, readError := zlib.NewReader(file)
            if readError != nil {
                log.Fatal(readError)
            }

            io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)
            r.Close()
        }
```

Comment: Note that the existing `go-git` package *is* a clone of Git in Go. So you're doing work others have already done. This is fine as an exercise, of course.

Comment: Absolutely. This is an exercise. In a position at work where I need to learn a lot more about the inner workings of Git.

Answer (score 1):

`blob 40\x00` is literally part of the (decompressed) file content. It is the object header:

- the type of the object (here "blob"; other types include "commit" and "tree", for instance)
- the object's size in bytes (here 40)
- and a null byte

You can't just remove that. You have to understand the header to make sense of the object content proper.

See [the "Git Internals - Git Objects" chapter of the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for further information.